# Do I need a Munich transit visa if I have an expired US visa?

Tags: air-travel, schengen, transit, indian-citizens, germany

Does an Indian citizen with valid passport and with expired US visa travel from USA to India via Munich without any transit visa?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [German consular website](https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/05-VisaEinreise/airport-transit-visa/924624), there is an exception to the transit visa requirement for those who "hold a used valid or expired visa issued by the USA and return from the USA
and travel to a non-Schengen Member State **within 24 hours after the expiration of their visa**"

The full list of exceptions is:

> Nationals of the above named countries Do NOT require an airport transit visa if
>
> 1. they hold a valid visa for the United States of America, or
> 2. they hold a used valid or expired visa issued by the USA and return from the USA and travel to a non-Schengen Member State within 24 hours after the expiration of their visa, or
> 3. they hold one of the following residence permits:
>
>    - Form I-551 permanent resident card (valid for 2 to 10 years),
>    - Form I-551 Alien registration receipt card (valid for 2 to 10 years),
>    - Form I-551 Alien registration receipt card (no expiry date),
>    - Form I-327 Re-entry document (valid for two years — issued to holders of a I551),
>    - Resident alien card (valid for 2 or 10 years or no expiry date. This document
>        guarantees the holder’s return only if his stay outside the USA has not exceeded
>        one year),
>    - Permit to re-enter (valid for two years. This document guarantees the holder’s
>        return only if his stay outside the USA has not exceeded two years),
>        Stand: April 2017
>    - Valid temporary residence stamp in a valid passport (valid for one year from the date of issue).
>    - Please note that the advance parole (I-512) and the approval notice (I-797) are not valid documents for visa free airport transit on your way back to the
>        United States of America.
> 4. they hold a valid visa for a Schengen Member State, Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland, Japan, Romania or UK, or
> 5. they hold a used valid or expired visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland, Japan, Romania or UK and return from the country of visa issuance and travel to a non-Schengen Member State.

The document from which the above list is taken is available from a PDF file linked on the aforementioned consular website.  The direct link is https://www.germany.info/blob/917514/80e28ec8a47bb057c06ca4023b155842/airport-transit-country-list-data.pdf.