# Can we travel to India via Frankfurt (transit) with an expired Canadian visa?

Tags: transit, frankfurt

Can we travel to India via Frankfurt (transit) with an expired Canadian visa? We do not have any other country's visa.

I am an Indian Citizen and my Canadian visa expired last Nov 2018. Now returning back to India from Canada.

Please assist!

Comment: What is your citizenship?  Are you coming from Canada?  If so, how recently did your visa expire?  Please edit your question to include these details.

Comment: Thanks for the Response Michael! I am an Indian Citizen and my Canadian VISA expired on Nov 2018. I am returning back to India from Canada.

Comment: See also [Question on Munich transit visa,](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134099/question-on-munich-transit-visa) which has a link to a German consulate site noting that you're allowed to use an expired Canadian visa to fly from Canada to India.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area) gives details of what kind of visa you are need to transit the Schengen area. A Canadian visa helps you only if it is valid, which yours us not. You need to apply for a Schengen transit visa.

Comment: [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=IN&DV=India&TC=DE&TV=Germany&h=16745de7598f61b8eeda998b52f102deca89ddd) says expired Candian visa is Ok for FRA as long as traveller is coming from Canada.

Comment: Note that the "canonical" answer was incomplete;  expired visas from Canada, Japan, or anywhere in the EU can be used to return home via Germany.  (Previously, the answer only mentioned expired US visas being allowed for such transits.)  I have edited the "canonical" answer accordingly.