# Travel from the US to Mumbai via Frankfurt on an expired H1B with a valid Canadian visitor visa

Tags: canada, transit-visas, lufthansa, h1b-visas, frankfurt

I am travelling from the US to India via Frankfurt (Germany) in a couple of weeks. My US H1B visa has expired (with an approved I-797), but I do have a valid Canadian visitor visa.

The German Mission of the US has a document which lists Indian passport holders who need a transit visa, unless they have a valid US or Canadian visa, or an expired visa from the departing country (the US or Canada), provided the visa has not expired over 24 hours ago. So, while I do have a valid Canadian visa, I am not sure if the expired US visa will cause me an issue, as my departing flight is from the US. Can someone with similar experience or knowledge of this scenario help me?

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134099/do-i-need-a-munich-transit-visa-if-i-have-an-expired-us-visa) show that you do not need a transit visa if you are returning from the US and have a US visa, even if it is expired. An expired US visa just means you cannot enter the US with it, not that you were in the US illegally.

Comment: @DJClayworth but Germany inexplicably and possibly illegally puts a 24-hour limit on using an expired US visa as a transit visa exemption, as noted in this question.

Comment: @phoog Genuine question: why ‘possibly illegally’? Does the USA allow transit with an expired visa issued by another country?